# Azure Integration Account, use public and private certificate in agreement

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am currently setting up an Integration account on Azure. When defining an agreement I want the messages both signed and encrypted, but I can not supply the private certificate as I keep getting this message

> There were no private certificates found. Please create a certificate with both private key and public certificate

I have added the private and public certificates as described in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-certificates) Microsoft guide, and the picture below

[image: Adding certificates to integration account]

But I can not use them when defining the agreement afterwards as shown in the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your certificate doesn't meet the requirements. I test it by creating the certificate in azure key vault it works fine.

I go to my azure key vault and click "Certificates" --> "Generate/Import".
[image]

Then create the certificate.
[image]

Wait a few minutes, the status of the certificate will become "Enabled", then download it to local.
[image]

After that, go to your integration account and upload the certificate to it.
[image]

Now, we can find it when we want to add agreements.
[image]

In this way I generate the certiticate, I can choose it when add the agreements. Hope it helps~

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed! The step where you have to download the cer version and include that file when defining a private certificate seems near impossible to find.